# How to add searchview in actionbar and search from listview

Tags: android, searchview

i implemented listview and now i want to implement search functionality on list-view

Here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return true;
}
```

How can i achieve search on list-view.i am not getting how to achieve other functionality also after search and update list

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_product_detail, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.getQuery();
    Log.v("Abhijit", "" + searchManager.QUERY.toString());
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}
```

How can i achieve search on list-view.i am not getting how to achieve other functionality also after search and update list

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ this link might be helpful for you

Comment: i am new to android could you please tell me the solution in my code please

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

Activity File:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

     MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = null;
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
    }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

manifest file:

```
<meta-data 
      android:name="android.app.default_searchable" 
      android:value="com.apkgetter.SearchResultsActivity" /> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.apkgetter.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

searchable xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Implement filterable to you listview adapter to filter the list according to searched data.

Comment: i want to add filter function

Answer (score 0):

This is how you filter in adapter:

```
public class FavouritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouritesAdapter.MyViewHolder>  implements Filterable {

    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private ArrayList<ProductDetail> listItems, filterList;
    private Context context;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textView        = (TextView)    view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }

    public FavouritesAdapter(Context context, List<ProductDetail> listItems) {
        this.context    = context;
        this.listItems  = listItems;
        this.filterList = new ArrayList<ProductDetail>();
        // we copy the original list to the filter list and use it for setting row values
        this.filterList.addAll(this.listItems);
    }

    @Override
    public FavouritesAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_favourites, parent, false);

        return new FavouritesAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FavouritesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(filterList.get(position));
    }

    // Clean all elements of the recycler
    public void clear() {
        filterList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // Add a list of items
    public void addAll(List<ProductDetail> list) {
        filterList.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != filterList ? filterList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<ProductDetail> list = listItems;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<ProductDetail> nlist = new ArrayList<ProductDetail>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i).getYourObject; // get Your Object against whom you want to compare the list
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(listItems.get(i));
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
            filterList = (ArrayList<ProductDetail>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

In your activity:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(searchedEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I used ArrayList<ProductDetail>

Comment: String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i).getYourObject; 
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(listItems.get(i));
                }
            }   // get your object with whom you want to compare the the search in you list